# Unable to establish SSL connection, how do I fix my SSL cert?

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, wget

I'm trying to `wget` to my own box, and it can't be an internal address in the wget (so says another developer).

When I wget, I get this:

```
wget http://example.com
--2013-03-01 15:03:30--  http://example.com/
Resolving example.com... 172.20.0.224
Connecting to example.com|172.20.0.224|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://www.example.com/ [following]
--2013-03-01 15:03:30--  https://www.example.com/
Resolving www.example.com... 172.20.0.224
Connecting to www.example.com|172.20.0.224|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I believe it is because I do not have the certificate setup properly. Using openssl:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
15586:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:588:
```

While if I do the same command on another site, it shows the entire cert.

Perhaps the ssl cert was never setup in the conf file on Apache for that domain?

If so, what should I be specifying in the virtualhost? Is there any alternative other than specifying `--no-check-certificate` because I don't want to do that?

Comment: Enable SSL/TLS on the port at the server. The error usually means HTML (served over HTTP) is being interpreted as a SSL Record (as if it was served over HTTPS). Also see the following on creating a certificate with all required names and IP addresses (and not just one name): [How can I generate a self-signed certificate with SubjectAltName using OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21488845).

Answer (score 103, accepted):

> SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

This error happens when OpenSSL receives something other than a `ServerHello` in a protocol version it understands from the server.  It can happen if the server answers with a plain (unencrypted) HTTP.  It can also happen if the server only supports e.g. TLS 1.2 and the client does not understand that protocol version.  Normally, servers are backwards compatible to at least SSL 3.0 / TLS 1.0, but maybe this specific server isn't (by implementation or configuration).

It is unclear whether you attempted to pass `--no-check-certificate` or not.  I would be rather surprised if that would work.

A simple test is to use `wget` (or a browser) to request `http://example.com:443` (note the `http://`, not `https://`); if it works, SSL is not enabled on port 443.  To further debug this, use `openssl s_client` with the `-debug` option, which right before the error message dumps the first few bytes of the server response which OpenSSL was unable to parse.  This may help to identify the problem, especially if the server does not answer with a `ServerHello` message.  To see what exactly OpenSSL is expecting, check the source: look for `SSL_R_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL` in `ssl/s23_clnt.c`.

In any case, looking at the apache error log may provide some insight too.

Comment: Thank you very much for the `wget` tip!

Comment: "Normally, servers are backwards compatible to at least SSL 3.0 / TLS 1.0, but maybe this specific server isn't". For example a Synology NAS since DSM 6.2. Only accepts TLS v1.2 or higher by default.

Comment: Yes — the world of SSL/TLS was very different 7 years ago when that answer was written.

Answer (score 21):

In my case I had not enabled the site 'default-ssl'. Only '000-default' was listed in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` folder.

Enable SSL site on Ubuntu 14 LTS, Apache 2.4.7:

```
a2ensite default-ssl
service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Or in my case, just restarting `apache2` (apparently I had forgotten to do that after adding the SSL vhost config). D'oh!

Answer (score 16):

**Just a quick note** (and possible cause).

You can have a perfectly correct `VirtualHost` setup with `_default_:443` etc. in your Apache .conf file.

*But...* If there is even one .conf file enabled with incorrect settings that also listens to port 443, then it will bring the whole SSL system down.

Therefore, if you are sure your .conf file is correct, try disabling the other site .conf files in `sites-enabled`.

Comment: This just solved my problem after hours of debugging. Check every single included vhost that is using SSL/TLS and confirm that all are valid. Disable all of them and then test one at a time until you find the culprit.

Comment: I read dozens and dozens of pages and posts on debugging SSL configurations. This is the first one that pointed at the fact that all SSL configs in the server must be correct or nothing will work. This WAS my problem. I had forgotten that I had an incomplete setup for another client. One quick search and liberal use of the # and away we go!  THANKS!

Answer (score 4):

There are a few possibilities:

1. <del>Your workstation doesn't have the root CA cert used to sign your server's cert.  How exactly you fix that depends on what OS you're running and what release, etc.</del>  (I suspect this is not related)
2. <strike>Your cert isn't installed properly.  If your SSL cert requires an intermediate cert to be presented and you didn't set that up, you can get these warnings.</strike>
3. Are you sure you've enabled SSL on port 443?

For starters, to eliminate (3), what happens if you telnet to that port?

Assuming it's not (3), then depending on your needs you may be fine with ignoring these errors and just passing --no-certificate-check.  You probably want to use a regular browser (which generally will bundle the root certs directly) and see if things are happy.

If you want to manually verify the cert, post more details from the `openssl s_client` output.  Or use `openssl x509 -text -in /path/to/cert` to print it out to your terminal.

Comment: I fail to see how 1) could ever possibly lead to an "unknown protocol" error at `s23_clnt.c:588`.  2) possibly, if the server falls back to plain HTTP giving an error message.

Comment: That's true, I'll remove that, thanks.  My suspicion is that it's (3), and your answer indicates you clearly agree.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when setting up a new EC2 instance. I had not added HTTPS to my security group, and so port 443 was not open.

Answer (score 1):

For me a DNS name of my server was added to /etc/hosts and it was mapped to 127.0.0.1 which resulted in

> SL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Removing mapping of my real DNS name to 127.0.0.1 resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I  meet this same question. The port 443 wasn't open in Centos.

Check the 443 port with the following command:

> sudo lsof -i tcp:443

In the first line of */etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf* add this two lines:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened for me only in special cases, when I called website from some internet providers,

I've configured only ip v4 in VirtualHost configuration of apache, 
but some of router use ip v6, and when I added ip v6 to apache config the problem solved.

Answer (score -2):

The problem I faced was in client server environment. The client was trying to connect over http port 80 but wanted the server proxy to redirect the request to some other port and data was https. So basically asking secure information over http. So server should have http port 80 as well as the port client is requesting, let's say `urla:1111\subB`.

The issue was server was hosting this on some other port e,g `urla:2222\subB`; so the client was trying to access over 1111 was receiving the error. Correcting the port number should fix this issue. In this case to port number 1111.