# Yeoman generator-generator giving error when running

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am using WindowsXP and tryign to create my first yeoman angular project

I installed npm, yo, grunt-cli, generator-generator etc.

when i run

```
 yo generator
```

I am getting flowing error

> D:\OpenSource\html\generator-jbake>yo generator
>
> ```
>  _-----_
> |       |
> |--(o)--|   .--------------------------.    `---------'  |    Welcome to Yeoman,    |
> ( _'U`_ )   |   ladies and gentlemen!  |
> /___A___\   '__________________________'
>  |  ~  |    __'.___.'__  '   `  |° ' Y `
> ```
>
> [?] Would you mind telling me your username on GitHub? raj[?]
>   What's the base name of your generator? jbake
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\hegdera\Application
>   Data\npm\node_modules\generator-generator\app\index.js:38
>         throw err;
>               ^ 2636:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
>   protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:766:
>
> ```
> at Object.proto.sendError (C:\Documents and Settings\hegdera\Application
> ```
>
> Data\npm\node_modules\generator-generator\node_modules\github\api\v3.0.0\index.js:30:19)
>       at C:\Documents and Settings\hegdera\Application Data\npm\node_modules\generator-generator\node_modules\github\api\v3.0.0\user.js:36:29
>       at ClientRequest. (C:\Documents and Settings\hegdera\Application
>   Data\npm\node_modules\generator-generator\node_modules\github\index.js:719:17)
>       at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
>       at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at SecurePair. (tls.js:1392:15)
>       at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at SecurePair.error (tls.js:1012:27)
>       at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:457:17)

Anyone tell me what is the problme ?

Answer (score 0):

I installed [generator-generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-generator) locally and ran the same command "**yo generator**" and it **worked well**.

I tested on **Windows XP** and **Node v0.10.26 , yo v1.3.2**.

The error you get has some issues related to proxy/ssl settings. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166950/unable-to-establish-ssl-connection-how-do-i-fix-my-ssl-cert) & [this](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-generator/issues/36) it may help resolve it.