# Apache kafka consumer java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-security

I'm trying to connect to remove kafka broker as consumer using 0.11.0.3 kafka version via SSL using commandline tool, connection string is the following

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat \
    --bootstrap-server host:port \
    --topic topicName \
    --from-beginning \
    --group groupId \
    --consumer.config ssl.properties
```

`ssl.properties` file

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=path/to/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=1234567
ssl.keystore.location=path/to/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=1234567
ssl.key.password=1234567
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
```

Exception I get

```
[2020-04-28 17:24:39,522] ERROR [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=binomix] Connection to node -1 (/178.208.149.84:9301) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-28 17:24:39,524] ERROR Error processing message, terminating consumer process:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1582)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:544)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1216)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1184)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:471)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeWrap(SslTransportLayer.java:448)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:313)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:265)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:547)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:535)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:235)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:317)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1226)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1191)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1176)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$ConsumerWrapper.receive(ConsoleConsumer.scala:439)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.process(ConsoleConsumer.scala:105)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.run(ConsoleConsumer.scala:77)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:54)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:333)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:325)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1689)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:226)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1082)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:1015)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:1012)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1520)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.runDelegatedTasks(SslTransportLayer.java:402)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:484)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:340)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:145)
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:94)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:459)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:440)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:284)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1676)
        ... 27 more
Processed a total of 0 messages
```

Any ideas why it happens? Is it an issue with certificates? I did not generate them, they were given me by kafka server owner.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that Subject Alternative Name (SAN) is missing from your brokers' certificates (for example `/var/private/ssl/kafka.server.truststore.jks`).

To do so, append the argument `-ext SAN=DNS:{FQDN}` to the keytool command:

```
keytool \ 
    -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks \
    -alias localhost \
    -validity {validity} \
    -genkey \
    -keyalg RSA \
    -ext SAN=DNS:{FQDN}
```

---

Make sure to inclued SAN when creating servers' keystores. This is also mentioned in the [Confluent's Security Tutorial](https://docs.confluent.io/current/security/security_tutorial.html#configuring-host-name-in-certificates):

> If host name verification is enabled, clients will verify the server’s
> fully qualified domain name (FQDN) against one of the following two
> fields:
>
> 1. Common Name (CN)
> 2. Subject Alternative Name (SAN)
>
> Both fields are valid, however [RFC-2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818) recommends the use of SAN. SAN is also more flexible,
> allowing for multiple DNS entries to be declared. Another advantage is
> that the CN can be set to a more meaningful value for authorization
> purposes.

---

Alternatively, you can choose to [disable server host verification](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html#optional-settings):

> Disable server host name verification by setting
> `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm` to an empty string.

Therefore, you just need to set in `server.properties` the following configuration and **finally restart your Kafka Cluster**:

```
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that inclusion of the 'SAN' when generating the key-pair (and hence the key-store) is not enough.

```
keytool \ 
    -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks \
    -alias {alias} \
    -validity {validity} \
    -genkey \
    -keyalg RSA \
    -ext SAN=DNS:{FQDN}
```

This needs to be followed by inclusion of the 'SAN' when creating the certificate signing request as well.

```
keytool \ 
    -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks \ 
    -alias {alias} \ 
    -certreq -ext SAN=DNS:{FQDN} 
    -file {csr_filename}
```

One can verify the certificate signing request thus created, and it should have the relevant SAN present.

```
keytool \ 
    -v -printcertreq -file {csr_filename}
```

Later, if openssl's x509 command is used to fulfil the certificate signing request, care should be taken to explicitly include the x509 version 3 extensions. The 'SAN' is one such extension and unless explicitly included, will not find its way into the certificate that is finally issued.
The concept is discussed in detail here - [Subject Alternative Name not present in certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30977264/subject-alternative-name-not-present-in-certificate).