# How to make browser accept a ssl certificate with a full certificate chain?

Tags: ssl, browser, https, openssl

I like to create my own PKI with a root CA and a intermediate CA finally signing a server certificate.
For creation of the certificates I used openssl and got these:

cert.pem

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

ca_cert.pem:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

root_cert.pem

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Verifing these via openssl results in

```
.\openssl.exe verify -show_chain -CAfile root_cert.pem -untrusted ca_cert.pem cert.pem
cert.pem: OK
Chain:
depth=0: C = DE, ST = Niedersachsen, L = Osnabrueck, O = MyCompany GmbH, OU = Geschaeftsfuehrung, CN = localhost (untrusted)
depth=1: C = DE, ST = Niedersachsen, L = Osnabrueck, O = MyCompany GmbH, OU = Geschaeftsfuehrung, CN = MyCompany primary CA (untrusted)
depth=2: C = DE, ST = Niedersachsen, L = Osnabrueck, O = MyCompany GmbH, OU = Geschaeftsfuehrung, CN = MyCompany root CA
```

I also created a *chain.pem* file by concatinate all certs into it in the same order as listed above.

Now, I give the *chain.pem* to my Webserver as cert-file. I also added the root_cert.pem to my Operating System as trusted with this command.

```
PS> Import-Certificate -FilePath ./root_cert.pem -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
```

Now opening the browser I got errors

- *Chrome* says **NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID**
- *FireFox* says **SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER**

If I click on show certificate, both browsers list the certificates above.

Unfortunately the browsers dont tell me the exact issues they have or give a hint how to solve them.

May I ask for help regarding my specific problem and also for a nice reference for what exactly is required to make a browser trust a server certificate created with a chain by yourself, so other people who encounter similar problems may find help? Thanks!

**Remark:** I only want to add the *root_cert.pem* as trusted to the operating system, and not any intermediate certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2017 there was a change in how browsers check certificates for validity. Instead of using the common name (**cn**), they now use the **subjectAltName**.
see also: [heise](https://www.heise.de/hintergrund/Chrome-blockt-ab-sofort-Zertifikate-mit-Common-Name-3717594.html)

The **subjectAltName** is a extenstion to a certificate and needs to be added to it, continaing the DNS or IP of the host.

Hence it is an extension, it is not part of the subject standard of *openssl*.
See [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/provide-subjectaltname-to-openssl-directly-on-the-command-line) how to set the **subjectAltName** for *openssl*.

On top of that *openssl* has a known bug, that will prevent the transfer of the
*subjectAltName*-extension on signing a request. You need to set it manually via a config file. CLI also not supported here. Find the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30977264/subject-alternative-name-not-present-in-certificate)

---

**FireFox** send the mentioned error because it do not link to the operating system for Root-CA, you need to add it separately to FireFox.

---

Finally, if you encounter any problems of validity of your created certificate:

- Use **FireFox** to check your https conncection, hence FireFox provide more detailed Error messages thon other browsers.

  - dont forget to add your Root-CA to its dedicated cert-store.
- Check Security & Signing **Algorithms**. They have to be up to date for all certificates!
- Check for a correct **subjectAltName** to be present and valid (exactly the same value as in the reqeust URL).
- Make sure your **webserver sends** not only its certificate, but the **whole chain**. Else there will be unknown issuer error, if you use a intermediate CA. [See here](https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm)