# Does Secure Gateway Client support self-signed cert which CN is IP address?

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I set up Secure Gateway's destination with HTTPS option + Client TLS: enabled in order to access remote HTTPS REST API which CN is IP address.

[image]

When I executed a trx, the Secure Gateway Client got the error "IP: 192.168.56.1 is not in the cert's list:". There was no information of CN name.  If the cert had not been uploaded to SG, the error message was to be "DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT" regarding the "Secure Gateway client troubleshooting". So I think the cert was uploaded correctly, but CN was not resolved by SG Client.

Secure Gateway client troubleshooting
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/SecureGateway/ts_index-gentopic1.html#ts_sg_010

Could you teach me whether Secure Gateway Client support self-signed cert which CN is IP address or not ?

**Secure Gateway Client's log**

> [2015-07-06 08:16:26.548] [INFO] Connection #55 is being established to 192.168.56.1:443
>   [2015-07-06 08:16:26.580] [INFO] Connection #55 established to 192.168.56.1:443
>   [2015-07-06 08:16:26.656] [ERROR] Connection #55 to destination 
> 192.168.56.1:443 had error: IP: 192.168.56.1 is not in the cert's list:
>   [2015-07-06 08:16:26.676] [INFO] Connection #55 to 192.168.56.1:443 was closed

**uploaded cert file**
CN=192.168.56.1, OU=demo, O=qit, L=hakozaki, S=tokyo, C=Japan
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error message it does not say CN, (e.g. [ERROR] Connection # had error: Host: . is not cert's CN: ), but the cert's list, which leads me to believe you have generated your self-signed cert incorrectly.  The problem is generating the cert using an FQDN or CN with an IP_Address.  This will not work since IP addresses are only supported when using SAN.

Method for generating a certificate with an IP as the CN with openssl:

1) create an openssl config file, I copied mine from /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

2) Add an alternate_names section to the file like below:

```
[ alternate_names ]
IP.1 = <my application's ip>
```

3) In the [ v3_ca ] section, add this line:

```
subjectAltName = @alternate_names
```

4) Under the CA_default section, uncomment copy_extensions:

```
# Extension copying option: use with caution.
copy_extensions = copy
```

5) Gen private key:
openssl genrsa -out private.key 3072

6) Gen certificate with options about organization:
openssl req -new -x509 -key private.key -sha256 -out certificate.pem -days 730 -config

7) Combine the files:
cat private.key certificate.pem > SAN.pem

8) Load the SAN.pem file into your destination as the client-TLS cert.

9) Load the SAN.pem file into your on-premises application and restart.

10) Your destination can be configured for either TCP, HTTP or HTTPS and you cloud side application should now be able to connect to your on-premises application.

Got this from:
[How can I generate a self-signed certificate with SubjectAltName using OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488845/how-can-i-generate-a-self-signed-certificate-with-subjectaltname-using-openssl)

Comment: Yes. I added information about my cert in my question. Is there any cause ?

Comment: Reproducing what you have done in the lab using an IP address, HTTPS + ClientTLS, will let you know what I find out as soon as this is completed.

Comment: I have replicated your issue and we formulating a fix for you at this time.  Will let you know when we have a fix.

Comment: We have a defect open for the issue, will post here when a fix is ready.

Comment: Hi, I know some time has passed but... what is the fix  ?