# Logstash-forwarder says certificate signed by unknown authority when using a self-signed certificate with SubjectAltName

Tags: ssl, logstash-forwarder

I'm trying to connect to logstash with logstash-forwarder. Their communication base on ssl so I generate a self-signed certificate follows [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488845/how-can-i-generate-a-self-signed-certificate-with-subjectaltname-using-openssl). Then I got this error message on logstash-forwarder side:

> Failed to tls handshake with 9.21.61.19 x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: invalid signature: parent certificate cannot sign this kind of certificate" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "*.*.*.*.*")

If I generate the certificate without subject alt name, it will work.
The worked certificate can be generated by:

> openssl req -x509  -batch -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout lumberjack.key -out lumberjack.crt -subj /CN=*.*.*.*.*

But what I'm hoping to do is to generate a certificate which can be used in different kinds of host. To do that I want to generate a ssl certificate whose CN=*.*.*.*.*, then alt names include *, *.*, *.*.* etc.

Is there any suggestion on how can I overcome this ssl error? Or a better way to make logstash-forwarder can work in a variety of environments?

Comment: Names can only contain a single wildcard and only left-most. That is no `foo.*.example.com` and no `*.*.example.com` but only `*.example.com`.

Comment: Really? when I use CN=*.*.*.*.* , it do work in my environment.

Comment: It might be that logstash does not properly verify certificates then, but according to RFC 6125 such broad wild cards should not be accepted. No browser will accept this either.

Comment: So you are saying my requirement is impossible to achieve? Do we have another way to work around this? I mean, to generate a certificate works on hosts with all kind of hostname? I know this is not ssl designed to works. But to make logstash-forwarder and logstash works in my production environment I do need this...

Comment: I have no idea of the specifics of your environment. Apart from that this sounds more like professional server management so please ask at [serverfault.se](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot for your patience and knowledge sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, when I removed the

> keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

in `[ v3_ca ]`, which is asked in the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488845/how-can-i-generate-a-self-signed-certificate-with-subjectaltname-using-openssl), the generated certificate do works for a variety of host names.

This may not be a right scenario for SSL. But for the logstash/logstash-forwarder case, it do helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you mentioned the pem file in "ssl ca" the logstash-forwarder.conf ? You have to mention the pem file which is used to sign the certificate in conf.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes,I updated the "ssl ca" in logstash-forwarder.conf. It resolved the issue.  Thanks