# Chrome accept self-signed localhost certificate

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, self-signed

i did follow all the answers on 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)
and nothing worked for me... nothing at all.
I'm on windows 10, using chrome version 54.0.2840.99 m
trying to access my QNAP TS-453a on local on a static ip address (10.1.1.1)
https://10.1.1.1/cgi-bin/

I tried using imported certificates, self signed, export and import the default one, etc nothing works

Some help would be really really appreciated

Comment: What am I supposed to do to get Chrome to accept the certificate and stop complaining about it?

Answer (score 26):

*Valid as of Chrome v58.0.3029*:

1. Visit the site in Chrome.
2. Open Developer Tools (F12)

   - Navigate to Security tab
   - Click "View certificate"

     - Click Details > Copy to file
     - Choose a save location on your local machine
3. Open Chrome settings

   - Toggle "Show Advanced Settings" (bottom of screen)
   - Navigate to HTTPS/SSL > Manage certificates

     - Click "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"
     - Click Import
     - Navigate to the cert you just stored
4. Quit Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+Q) and re-visit your site

NOTE:

Chrome recently (as of 05/15/17) began to require that the cert's **subjectAltName** parameter be filled. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488845/how-can-i-generate-a-self-signed-certificate-with-subjectaltname-using-openssl) received an answer that tells you how to do so.

Comment: Updated June 2021 - Windows 10 - Chrome v91 answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67855484/3009639

Comment: The Private Key for this Client Certificate is missing or invalid

Answer (score 4):

In general, to troubleshoot this kind of problem, open Developer Tools, go to Security tab, and you will see what Chrome deems wrong with that certificate.

It is likely that it doesn't include a `subjectAltName` extension, and the solution for adding one is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56530824/2873507