# Chrome showing Invalid certificate/ Connection not secure

Tags: google-chrome, iis, certificate, x509certificate

I have created a certificate using powershell using the below command

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject “CN=”ids” -CertStoreLocation “cert:\Localmachine\My”
```

I have copied this certificate in Trusted root certificate also. Setup the IIS to use this certiicate but chrome is displaying error Not secure (NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID). Please refer the attachments for the settings and issue

Please help me to solve this issue

[image: Chrome Invalid Certificate]
[image: Chrome Not Secure]
[image: IIS Settings]
[image: Personal Certificate created]
[image: Copied to trusted Certificate in Localmachine]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NET::ERR\_CERT\_COMMON\_NAME\_INVALID - Error Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138678/neterr-cert-common-name-invalid-error-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject “CN=ids” -DnsName ”ids”, ”idsDomin1”,”idsDomin2” -CertStoreLocation “cert:\Localmachine\My”
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add "127.0.0.1 ids" in hosts file.

Second, change powershell command line to generate the certificate again. Delete the old one and use this new.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "ids" -CertStoreLocation “cert:\Localmachine\My”
```

Comment: Yes , Providing DnsName will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Disabling HTTP/2 worked for me using an IIS self-signed certificate.