# How to create self-signed VALID certificate for chrome and Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, firefox, https, certificate

i read several posts about how to create a self-signed certificate, however even if the certificate is created correctly, Firefox instead of showing me a green lock, it shows a warning symbol on green lock as "Connection is not Secure", while in Chrome instead of showing a green text, it displays a red text as "Not secured" and "Certificate Invalid".

So what should i do for local development to have it as valid certificate (except to purchase one) for my linux OS ?

i tried everything written on https://serverfault.com/questions/845766/generating-a-self-signed-cert-with-openssl-that-works-in-chrome-58 but without success to get the green TRUSTED and Valid certificate under chrome 64.x

What was valid for Chrome 58 seems to be invalid for Chrome 64.x

thx

Comment: i tried everything written on [link]https://serverfault.com/questions/845766/generating-a-self-signed-cert-with-openssl-that-works-in-chrome-58[/link] but without success to get the green TRUSTED and Valid certificate under chrome 64.x
 and everything on [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951939/chrome-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate[/link] does not work as well.
What was valid for Chrome 58 seems to be invalid for Chrome 64.x

Comment: Even trying to create a file named /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/EnableCommonNameFallbackFor‌​LocalAnchors.json with the contents: { "EnableCommonNameFallbackForLocalAnchors": true } did not help in Chrome v64

Comment: To troubleshoot this issue, open Developer Tools, go to Security tab, and you will see what the problem is. It is likely to be a lack of subjectAltName extension in the certificate, which you can fix with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56530824/2873507