# Node.js self signed certificate is still showing as "not trusted" in my browser

Tags: node.js, ssl

I am running a Node.js server and I'm trying to host this server locally and not get any SSL errors.

Here's what I did to create the certificate.  I opened up Terminal in Visual Studio Code and typed the following:

```
$ openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.cert
```

This created a .cert and a .key file in my current directory.

Next, in my app.js file, I added this:

```
https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('./server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.cert')//,
  //passphrase: ''
}, app)
.listen(3000);
```

I then ran the command `node app.js` in my terminal window to start the Node.js server.

I then visited `https://localhost:3000/` and am getting the following - notice "Not secure" - this is what I am trying to get rid of:

[image]

At this point, I did some Googling and saw where it might be helpful to export this certificate, and import directly into Chrome. I did this by clicking on the "Not secure" button and Click on Certificate:

[image]

Then, clicking on Details and "Copy to file":

[image]

Then, I clicked Next on the next screen and chose `DER encoded binary X.509 (.CER)`:

[image]

I clicked Next and gave the exported certificate a name of serverMike.cer:

[image]

Then, I clicked Next and Finish:

[image]

Export was successful:

[image]

Finally, I go to import this exported certificate in Chrome settings and choose "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" as where to place this certificate in:

[image]

I then clicked Next and Finish.  I closed out of Chrome and opened it back up, visited https://localhost:3000 and receive the same "Not secure" message.  Is there something I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Step 0: this is not a programming question

Step 1: if you hadn't apparently suppressed the error you should have seen the 'Not secure' error *page* formerly said NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID and now says NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID and if you click on Advanced it says "This server could not prove that it is [domain]; its security certificate does not specify Subject Alternative Names."

Step 2: see
https://serverfault.com/questions/845766/generating-a-self-signed-cert-with-openssl-that-works-in-chrome-58
https://serverfault.com/questions/880804/can-not-get-rid-of-neterr-cert-common-name-invalid-error-in-chrome-with-self
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89319/creating-my-own-ca-for-an-intranet 
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172440/generate-x509-err-cert-common-name-invalid
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/provide-subjectaltname-to-openssl-directly-on-the-command-line
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/113484/followup-to-one-liner-to-create-cert-request-with-san
[Chrome accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951939/chrome-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)

BTW: since this is local, you don't need to export the cert from the browser prior to importing it. If you create the cert from `openssl req ... -x509 ...` with extension `.cer` or `.crt`, or rename or copy it that way, you can just doubleclick and then import to TrustedRoots. Or for *any* name you can run MMC and select Certificates, or just directly run certmgr.msc, and import from there.