# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname 192.168.1.2 not verified

Tags: android, https, hostname

I'm currently learning Android. For an assignment I need to make an app which requests a json over https using a self-signed certificate and an xampp server.

I've created the certificate using apache's tool makecert, added to android and set it up so that it would recognize however I keep getting this annoying error

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname 192.168.1.2 not verified:
                                                                             certificate: sha1/g6vc6lpQuz/43pvUpMYogNNiU2o=
                                                                             DN: CN=192.168.1.2/*,OU=Adi,O=Adi,L=Oradea,ST=Bihor,C=RO
                                                                             subjectAltNames: []
```

I've managed to identify this bit of code

```
            private HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifier() {
            return new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    //return true;
                    HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
                    return hv.verify("192.168.1.2/*", session);
                }
            };
        }
```

but I am stumped as how to fix it. I've looked at the other threads here and the solution of setting this to always return true does work but is not really acceptable.

I also tried creating a certificate with the CN `192.168.1.2/*` as I'm using multiple json files from xampps htdocs folder but still nothing

I've also tried creating a paired key using java keytool and exporting the file to a crt and key format but it caused apache to crash at startup

EDIT: One thing I've noticed is that no matter what CN I add in the certificate it always reads hostname as 192.168.1.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your certificate contains **subjectAltName** or not.
If not, you have to attach your IP to **subjectAltName** in **openssl.cnf** file. 
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21494483/9359778) link for more info.

That example adds DNS as subjectAltName you can add your IP as

```
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
IP.1 = 192.168.1.1
IP.2 = 192.168.1.2
```