# My webpage doesnt opens in IE but opens in chrome and firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, openssl

My webpage doesnt opens in IE but opens in chrome and firefox.
my server ssl supports TLS 1.0 TLS 1.1 TLS 1.2.
if i disable TLS 1.2 in IE settings manually then i am able to access my webpage.
may i know what could be the problem.
I am trying on Windows 7 machine IE11

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have forgotten some extensions needed for TLS 1.2 when generating your server certificate.

Could you try adding some of the extensions shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21494483/9841565 ?

Or, can you share the server's certificate attributes ?

As a reminder, according to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246, "The certificate type MUST be X.509v3, unless explicitly negotiated otherwise (e.g., [TLSPGP])."