# Register gitab-runner throws cannot assign requested address (ubuntu, docker)

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab-ci-runner

### Hello everyone,

I have been fighting with this for 7 days now and am getting nowhere (only frustrated). I really hope someone can help me. Please keep in mind that I am no network expert, as I believe the problem lies here.

### The problem:

Attempts to register a gitlab-runner results in this error:
[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlHEi.png)

### The setup

Everything is installed on a single server in my home network. So it's

```
                                         - Laptop accessing the server
Internet - Router (FritzBox) 192.168.1.1 - Server 192.168.1.100
                                         - Other
```

The server runs

- Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0

I got my gitlab and gitlab-runner working a few months ago without https (I figured being a one-man team inside my own network I don't need https). I used docker-compose to run gitlab, postgresql and redis and 'normal' docker to run a gitlab-runner. That too was a struggle for me and it took me a while to figure out that I had to use **url = "http://192.168.1.100:30080/"** to register the runner.

But then I decided to upgrade to https using a **self-signed certificate**. I did this because I wanted to use the gitlab-buildin docker registry to speed up my builds, and as I understand that requires https.

I succeeded with gitlab. I can view my repositores, push changed, create issues and whatnot. But, as the title says, I am unable to register a gitlab-runner over https.

### docker-compose.yml

Lets start with the docker-compose, which starts postgres, redis, gitlab and now also the gitlab-runner:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
postgresql:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
          max-size: "10m"
          max-file: "10"
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=xxxxxxxxxxx
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxx
        - POSTGRES_DB=xxxxxxxxxxx
    volumes:
        - /opt/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql:rw

redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:5-alpine
    logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
          max-size: "10m"
          max-file: "10"

gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de'
    logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
          max-size: "10m"
          max-file: "10"
    links:
        - postgresql:postgresql
        - redis:redis
    environment:
        GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
            # postgres
            postgresql['enable'] = false
            gitlab_rails['db_username'] = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
            gitlab_rails['db_password'] = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
            gitlab_rails['db_host'] = "postgresql"
            gitlab_rails['db_port'] = "5432"
            gitlab_rails['db_database'] = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
            gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = 'postgresql'
            gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = 'utf8'
            # redis
            redis['enable'] = false
            gitlab_rails['redis_host'] = 'redis'
            gitlab_rails['redis_port'] = '6379'
            # nginx
            nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
            registry_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
            # email
            gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
            gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.gmail.com"
            gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
            gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
            gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
            gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
            gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
            gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
            gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
            gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'
            # other
            gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 30022
            # https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl.html#lets-encrypt-integration
            external_url 'https://treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de:30443'
            # registry
            registry_external_url 'https://treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de:30090'
    ports:
        # host:container
        # both ports must match the port from external_url above
        - "30080:30080"
        # the mapped port must match ssh_port specified above.
        - "30022:22"
        # https
        - "30443:30443"
        # registry
        - "30090:30090"
    volumes:
        - /opt/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab:rw
        - /opt/gitlab/log:/var/log/gitlab:rw
        - /opt/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab:rw
    depends_on:
        - postgresql
        - redis

runner:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine'
    restart: always
    logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
          max-size: "10m"
          max-file: "10"
    volumes:
        - /opt/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
        - gitlab
```

As you can see, the url of my gitlab is https://treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de:30443.

### gitlab-runner register

And here is the registration code:

```
docker run --rm -t -i -v /opt/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine --debug register \
  --non-interactive \
  --executor "docker" \
  --docker-image alpine:3 \
  --url "https://treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de:30443" \
  --registration-token "xxxxxxxxxxx" \
  --description "gitlab-runner-docker" \
  --tag-list "build,test,deploy" \
  --locked="false"
```

which, wenn executed, results in this error:

```
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=6 revision=4c96e5ad 
version=12.9.0
Checking runtime mode                               GOOS=linux uid=0
Running in system-mode.

Trying to load /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de.crt ...
Dialing: tcp treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de:30443 ...
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=xxxxxxxx status=couldn't execute 
POST against https://treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de:30443/api/v4/runners: 
Post https://treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de:30443/api/v4/runners: 
dial tcp [2001:16b8:a582:1800:314f:5277:9434:77ad]:30443: 
connect: cannot assign requested address
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

According to [Supported options for self-signed certificates](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html) I copied the same certificate I created and use for my gitlab to **/opt/gitlab-runner/config/certs/treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de.crt**. The content beginns with -----BEGIN, so I think it is encoded in PEM.

### Firewall

ufw is inactive until this problem is resolved.

### Logs

As far as I can tell, the registration process is not reaching my gitlab, since I can find no signs of a request in the gitlab logs. This is why I believe I have a network problem.

### Probing gitlab-runner container

Using **docker-compose exec runner /bin/sh** I found out that:

#### ping gitlab

```
PING gitlab (172.22.0.5): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.22.0.5: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
64 bytes from 172.22.0.5: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.105 ms
64 bytes from 172.22.0.5: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.150 ms
64 bytes from 172.22.0.5: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.154 ms
64 bytes from 172.22.0.5: seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.151 ms
^C
--- gitlab ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.055/0.123/0.154 ms
```

**172.22.0.5** is exactly the IP of the docker-container **gitlab**, as expected. However, using **register** against **https://gitlab:30443** results in

```
Dialing: tcp gitlab:30443 ...
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=xxxxxx 
status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab:30443/api/v4/runners: Post https://gitlab:30443/api/v4/runners: dial tcp: lookup gitlab on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

#### ping treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de

```
PING treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de (2001:16b8:a582:1800:314f:5277:9434:77ad): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Address not available
```

Adding the line

```
172.22.0.5     treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de
```

to the **hosts** of the *gitlab-runner-container* makes the ping work, but the **register** still results in

```
Trying to load /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de.crt ...
Dialing: tcp treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de:30443 ...
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=xxxxxxxx status=couldn't execute POST against https://treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de:30443/api/v4/runners: Post https://treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de:30443/api/v4/runners: dial tcp [2001:16b8:a582:1800:314f:5277:9434:77ad]:30443: connect: cannot assign requested address
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

### /etc/hosts

#### of gitlab-runner docker container

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.22.0.4      0181ad73e31f
# manually added to make ping work
# 172.22.0.5: gitlab-container
172.22.0.5      treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de
```

#### of host / the server

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       HP-ProDesk-400-G5-Desktop-Mini

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

### The self-signed certificate

I used [this guide](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-run-gitlab-with-self-signed-ssl-certificate). Basically, I did **openssl genrsa** and used **treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de** and **FQDN**. The content starts with ----- BEGIN.

### More information

Thank you for reading all of this. If you want to help and need more information I will provide them as fast as I can. Thanks :)

edit: entered image description, typos, grammar (I am german), removed statement that this is my first question (not true, it is my second), added probing gitlab-container, changed ips to reflect the current state after my tinkering

Comment: Too little information. Please enter inside the container by `docker-compose exec runner /bin/sh` and diagnose it a little bit. IMHO the "runner" have no idea what is treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de and should be replaced by "gitlab" as one container can reach another by its name. Try `ping treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de` and `ping gitlab`. Ones you have more info post it here so we can help more.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

**ping gitlab** is successful:
64 bytes from 172.22.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
--- gitlab ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.055/0.123/0.154 ms

However, running **register** against **https://gitlab:30443** results in:
lookup gitlab on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host

**ping treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de** results in: 
PING treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de (2001:16b8:a582:1800:314f:5277:9434:77ad): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Address not available

Added to main post

Comment: So there is your answer. In order to reach gitlab you have to add treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de to the hosts. Refer to https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links

Comment: Im afraid that didnt work. I added the line "172.22.0.5 treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de" (after my tinkering 172.22.0.5 is the new ip of gitlab) to the hosts of the gitlab-runner container and ran register against treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de. Result: connect: cannot assign requested address. Added the result to main post with better formatting.

Comment: You added `links:  - "gitlab:treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de"` in the runner section?

Comment: Thank you for your continued effort:). I added the link to the runner-section of the docker-compose and executed "docker-compose up -d". I had to readd the line "172.22.0.5 treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de" to hosts of the runner-container because if was recreated. no difference, same error. on the register. How do I debug this kind of problem? It is very strange the the ping works but the register doesnt.

Comment: What if registration token changed? Without full info I have hard time to help. On the other hand you have hard time to provide full info. I suggest you poke around with it for a while and ask more specific questions.

Comment: No, unfortunately the token didnt change. I already tried for several days getting this to work before coming here. I was hoping that I was doing something very basic wrong (like: doing gitlab and gitlab-runner in docker-compose just doesnt work) which I just didnt see. Like I wrote in my question, I don't know networking very well. I guess the biggest problem is that I dont know how to debug this and that I can only poke around hoping to stumble upon the correct configuration.

Comment: Start from fundamentals. Use netcat, nmap or whatever you are familiar with to determine if your gitlab is even listening on that port.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working setup:
after noticing that running **register** against **192.168.1.100** resulted in a different error:
[different erros for different register targets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0tdY.png)

I created a self-signed SSL using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488845/how-can-i-generate-a-self-signed-certificate-with-subjectaltname-using-openssl) which includes **192.168.1.100** alongside treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de. Than I moved that into *gitlab-runner/config/certs/ca.crt* instead of gitlab-runner/config/certs/treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de.crt.

```
[ v3_ca ]
subjectAltName = @alternate_names

# added manually
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488845/how-can-i-generate-a-self-signed-certificate-with-subjectaltname-using-openssl

[ alternate_names ]

DNS.1 = treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de
DNS.2 = www.treffer-technologies.home-webserver.de
IP    = 192.168.1.100
```

With that, gitlab-runner picked up the certificate and the register was successful. No need to edit any **hosts** or add additional networks or links to docker. I dont know if this is the proper way to do it but at least it works for me