# error during installation sylius

Tags: ssl, composer-php, sylius

i try install sylius from the [manual](http://sylius.org/get-started)

and I got a problem

> **php composer.phar create-project sylius/sylius-standard -s dev**

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                           
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:  
  error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol                                                                
  Failed to enable crypto                                                                                                            
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

How to resolve this problem?
command **php composer** not have **ssl** parametr

```
create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [package] [directory] [version]
```

version my ssl

```
>openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to establish SSL connection, how do I fix my SSL cert?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166950/unable-to-establish-ssl-connection-how-do-i-fix-my-ssl-cert)

Comment: @Oldskool ist link describes this problem, but not fix/
command php composer.phar not support ssl parametr. I research before and read your link