# Docker PHP71 curl works PHP72 not working

Tags: php, docker, nginx, php-7.2, fpm

I have a docker container that I have changed the Dockerfile from `php:7.1-fpm` to `php:7.2-fpm`. I have not made any other changes however I am unable to do HTTPS cURLs I am given the following curl error for all HTTPS requests. HTTP works fine.

> error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Any ideas?

Comment: PHP 7.1
Curl Extension (7.38.0) detected.
SSL Version (OpenSSL/1.0.1t) detected.

PHP 7.2
Curl Extension (7.52.1) detected.
SSL Version (OpenSSL/1.0.2l) detected.

Comment: you need the curl-dev package I think... maybe libcurl4-openssl-dev as well

Comment: Seems to be an openSSL issue refer to this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166950/unable-to-establish-ssl-connection-how-do-i-fix-my-ssl-cert

Comment: Those dont seem to work :S I am using nginx not apache.