# Warning: fgets(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages

Tags: linux, symfony, certificate, ssl-certificate

i'm working on a web server in linux with symfony framwork 
I have ssl certificate 
when i want to send an email i'v got this errors

> Warning: fgets(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
>   error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
>   error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
>   error:0906700D:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_read_bio:ASN1 lib
>   error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Comment: you are using swiftmailer ?

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166950/unable-to-establish-ssl-connection-how-do-i-fix-my-ssl-cert/15168180#15168180

Comment: yesy I use  swiftmailer  bundle inside service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps , it's about problem in certificate from your machine , can you try this in your config file :

```
swiftmailer:
    # ... your other configs
    stream_options:
      ssl:
        allow_self_signed: true
        verify_peer: false
```